# Page scrolling when using tab key on form element only chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have form HTML which is inside iframe. Problem with form is when you use tab key on already filled element the page is scrolling. Ex. Fill name in name field then fill email then again go to name field and then press tab key. You can notice that page is scrolling. This is very strange issue, when I remove two or three `br` from the above the iframe then it is working fine.

Here is my HTML.

**form HTML**

```
<form id="UserForm">
            <fieldset>          
            <div class="FormField">
            <p class="clear clearfix">
            <span class="PosRelative">
            <input type="text" name="Name" class="required InpFormat" placeholder="* Name" tabindex="1"> <span class="CheckMark"></span>

            </span>
            <span class="PosRelative FloatNone">
            <input type="text" class="required InpFormat noSpace" name="Email" placeholder="* Email" tabindex="2"><span class="CheckMark" ></span>
            </span>

            </p>
            <p class="clear clearfix">
            <span class="PosRelative FloatNone">
                <input type="text" class="required InpFormat" name="Mobile" placeholder="* Mobile" tabindex="3"><span class="CheckMark"></span>            
            </span>
            </p>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Contact" class="btn">                

            </div>
            </div>              
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

**page HTML**

```
 <body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<iframe src="form.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="280" scrolling="no"></iframe>   
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</body>
```

Comment: If you mean the page goes up or down, I can't duplicate that. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3b3urtj8/). Anyway, I'm sure the problem will go away if you don't use `<br>` for layout.

Comment: This bug will not reproduce on jsfiddle. You can put this code in your html page then you can see that bug. I just put br for reference it has nothing to do with this bug

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed` to the element containing the form.

Answer (score -1):

Use tabindex. Like:

`<input type="text" tabindex=1>
<input type="text" tabindex=2>`

Comment: Can you elaborate a more on this?